Add a column and fill with the value calculated using values from other columns
I am a newer in R. I want to add a column 'GFR' to the dataframe, and fill the column with the values calculated using GFR = 175 ✖️ (SCR^-1.154) ✖️ (age^-0.203) ✖️ 1.212[if Race = 3] ✖️ 0.742[if Gender = 1].
Here is my dataframe:
ID Gender Age Race   SCR
1    93735      1  52    2 11.46
2    93830      1  67    0  6.34
3    93834      2  48    3  0.64
4    93851      2  74    3  1.07
5    93893      1  55    0  2.40
6    94017      1  54    3  3.01
7    94050      2  55    3  0.93
8    94073      1  69    0  1.46
9    94095      2  78    0  NA
10   94179      1  72    3  1.90
11   94348      1  80    3  1.62
12   94500      2  60    0  1.25
13   94634      2  80    3  1.19
14   94670      1  60    0  1.62
15   94677      2  25    3  0.77
16   94711      2  64    1  0.90
17   94724      2  80    3  1.22
18   94725      1  56    3  NA
19   94729      1  37    0  1.87
20   94750      1  80    3  1.34
21   94753      2  74    0  0.86
22   94792      1  66    0  7.43
23   94813      2  62    0  0.62
24   94847      2  80    0  2.16
25   94894      1  50    3  0.98
picture of the datafram
I can add a column by using: dataframe$GFR <- rep(NA, nrow(dataframe))
and I can just write out 'dataframe1['GFR'] = 175 * dataframe1['SCR'] * dataframe1['Age']'
But I don't how to deal with: GFR = 175 ✖️ (SCR^-1.154) ✖️ (age^-0.203) ✖️ 1.212[if Race = 3] ✖️ 0.742[if Gender = 1].

Funny multiplication signs you have.


But I don't how to deal with: GFR = 175 ✖️ (SCR^-1.154) ✖️ (age^-0.203) ✖️ 1.212[if Race = 3] ✖️ 0.742[if Gender = 1].

You can use logical indexing:
df$GFR = 175 * df$SCR^-1.154 * df$Age^-0.203
df[df$Race==3,]$GFR = df[df$Race==3,]$GFR * 1.212
df[df$Gender==1,]$GFR = df[df$Gender==1,]$GFR * 0.742


Thank you very much for your help! The book is very nice.
